# GUID Cast Exception

Tags: crm, guid

I'm using the following code in CRM 4.0 to get the GUID, but it is giving me a casting exception:

```
Guid id=new Guid(entity.Properties["incidentid"].ToString());
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following:

```
Guid id = ((Key)entity["incidentid"]).Value;
```